# How to make a rest call to SharePoint 2013 from node.js?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In my node.js app, I want to make a rest call to sharepoint 2013. This is the node.js code

```
function downloadData(res, key, success, fail) {    
    var opts = url.parse(key);


    opts.method = 'GET';
    opts.headers = {"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest":"0x146E2BDC9A21FDA62E793A0FC9793A530A5C6688BE194FB051703C8529B01A16607931C77D26EE61FA360AD04526F476A052FAC9B3C9277A5463AC20A27C3543,07 Mar 2016 15:37:18 -0000"};
    opts.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata=nometadata';

    var req = http.request(opts, function(response) {
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {
            success(res, str, key);
        });
    })

    //req.write(data);
    req.end();
}
```

I got the digest value from the client side, I did an alert statement, and copied it. I tried it on a sample url, which does work if I paste on the browser. When I run this, I get `401 unauthorized`.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`X-RequestDigest Header`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd964175(v=office.12).aspx) is used to *validate client requests* but **not** for authentication purposes.

Assuming your SharePoint sites utilizes `NTLM authentication` (default), you could utilize [httpntlm package](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm) that implements HTTP NTLM authentication flow and allows to perform HTTP requests as demonstrated below:

```
var credentials = {
    username: 'jdoe',
    password: 'password',
    domain: 'contoso'
};
var webUrl = "http://contoso.intranet.com";
var fileUrl = "/Shared Documents/guide.docx";


httpntlm.get({
    url: webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileUrl + "')/$value",
    username: credentials.username,
    password: credentials.password,
    domain: credentials.domain
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);


    console.log(res.body); //print data
});
```

Comment: Tried this but always got HTTP 401 errors, even with "playing" a little bit with credentials (trying all possible values for domain, like `<tenant>`, `<tenant>.sharepoint.com`... and username like `<username>`, `<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com`...).
Finally got better luck with package `sp-request` https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-request & basic authentication with login/pass (I will try other authentication ways to avoid the need of storing a password)